# Explicit formulas for meets and joins of uniform spaces

Tags: general-topology, lattice-orders, uniform-spaces

I want explicit formulas for meets and joins (and finite meets and joins) for sets of uniform spaces (where uniformities are ordered by inclusion).

And also for proximity spaces.

I am also interested in a proof that uniform and proximity spaces on a set form complete lattices (or at least lattices or meet/join semilattices).

Comment: OK, I see that join of uniform spaces is just join of filters (and it is similarly understood by me about join of proximities). The remaining question is about meets of uniform spaces and proximity spaces

Comment: From the previous comment it follows that sets of uniform spaces (and proximity spaces too) always have a join. So they are complete lattices. I am trying to write down the formulas for meets